# Why the default rule does not work in Yii2?

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I created a model with the following content:

```
class User extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord implements IdentityInterface
{
    const STATUS_DELETED = 0;
    const STATUS_ACTIVE = 10;

    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'user';
    }


    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['username', 'auth_key', 'password', 'status', 'created_at', 'updated_at'], 'required'],
            [['status', 'created_at', 'updated_at'], 'integer'],
            [['username', 'fullname', 'password', 'password_reset_token', 'email'], 'string', 'max' => 255],
            [['auth_key'], 'string', 'max' => 32],
            [['username'], 'unique'],

            ['status', 'default', 'value' => self::STATUS_ACTIVE],
            ['created_at', 'default', 'value' => 123],
            ['status', 'in', 'range' => [self::STATUS_ACTIVE, self::STATUS_DELETED]],
            ['status', 'filter', 'filter' => 'intval'],
        ];
    }

    //... some functions below
}
```

Now in the controller I do this:

```
$user = new User();
$user->username = 'admin';
$user->email = 'admin';
$user->setPassword('admin');
$user->generateAuthKey();
if ($user->validate()) {
     $user->save();
} else {
     return var_dump($user->errors);
}
```

And as a result I get an error:

```
array(3) {
    ["status"]=> array(1) {
        [0]=> string(29) "Status cannot be blank."
    }
    ["created_at"]=> array(1) {
        [0]=> string(56) "Created At cannot be blank."
    }
    ["updated_at"]=> array(1) {
        [0]=> string(60) "Updated At cannot be blank."
    }
}
```

why the default value specified in the model for `created_at` and `status` didn't apply? How to correctly specify the default value for attributes?

```
['status', 'default', 'value' => self::STATUS_ACTIVE],
['created_at', 'default', 'value' => 123],
```

Comment: Validations are performed before saving to database. Adding fields into required rule will result is validation failures. You can set default value as you did and remove them from required validation.

Comment: Validation rules are applied in the order you provided them so the rule `required` is fired before `default` rule.

Comment: As per Bizley… the validation takes place in the sequence you specify them. You specified “required” before “default”. As a result the variables have no value at the time of the “required” validation

Comment: Using `require` and `default` rule at same attribute during same scenario doesn't make sense in first place. `Require` rule says that **the attribute has to be set**. `Default` rule says that **the attribute doesn't have to be set**, if it's not set, the specified value will be used instead. That's pretty much oposite of `require` rule.